# Cómo inicio un servidor MySQL sin XAMPP?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, xampp

Hice un programa para computador que se conecta a una base de datos y pensaba en instalarlo en el computador de mi papá para probar pero luego caí en cuenta de que necesito iniciar el servidor para que el programa pueda conectarse a la base de datos. Entonces me preguntaba cómo hacer en ese caso, para que el usuario final no tenga que abrir XAMPP e iniciar la base de datos MySQL para que el programa pueda conectarse a la base de datos.

Comment: instalar un windows server o linux server como ubuntu server, centos, redhat, etc

Comment: que sistema operativo usas???... todo va depender de eso

Comment: Podrias seguir esta guia: https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/php/otros/xampp-instalacion-windows.html#administrador aunque en tu caso el servicio seria mysql no  apache o quizas tambien sea necesario

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende del alcance de tu aplicación y requerimientos.

Podés tener una base de datos local o en red.

- Base de datos local: Podrías instalar Mysql o sino SQLite como te indicaron.
- Base de datos en red: Todas las pc deben estar en la misma red y poder comunicarse entre ellas, levantas la la bd en una y todas las pc se conectan a la dirección IP de esa máquina e instancia (por ejemplo 192.168.1.10\MYSQLSERVER) - Tené en cuenta que el firewall de tu PC Servidor puede bloquear conexiones entrantes o salientes.

Espero que te sirva al menos para orientarte un poco.

Saludos!